# Socket.IO with Electron app to send front end data to back end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, electron

I've seen a lot of examples on how to implement socket.io, but none that I can find that maintain the structure of the electron app in the process (typically it's just using express instead). I was wondering how I could implement socket.io with a basic electron app? Here's my boiler plate code:

Client.js file:

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");

// When client successfully connects to server
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(`Connected to server`);
});

// Receive message from backend
socket.on("message", data => {
  console.log(`Server: ${data}`);
});
```

I'd like to receive the above `socket.on` actions in my electron code if possible (while keeping things inside the app as opposed removing the app code and doing this by opening the browser)

Electron.js boilerplate:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need set up a socket.io server inside your electron app. However, if you're trying to just send info from the frontend to the electron backend, you should look into ipc. It's a built-in to electron for sending data between the frontend and backend for electron apps.

Comment: Do you know what the socket setup would look like? That’s mostly where I’m struggling. I’ll look into ipc as well though!

Answer (score 0):

I will share my working example:

Server.ts

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export interface ServerToClientEvents {
  noArg: () => void;
  basicEmit: (a: number, b: string, c: Buffer) => void;
  withAck: (d: string, callback: (e: number) => void) => void;
}

export interface ClientToServerEvents {
  hello: () => void;
}

interface InterServerEvents {
  ping: () => void;
}

interface SocketData {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const io = new Server<
  ClientToServerEvents,
  ServerToClientEvents,
  InterServerEvents,
  SocketData
>({
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:1212"
  }
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log('Server received new connection');
  socket.emit("noArg");
  socket.emit("basicEmit", 1, "2", Buffer.from([3]));
  socket.emit("withAck", "4", (e) => {
    // e is inferred as number
  });

  // works when broadcast to all
  io.emit("noArg");

  // works when broadcasting to a room
  io.to("room1").emit("basicEmit", 1, "2", Buffer.from([3]));

  socket.on("hello", () => {
    console.log('Server received hello!');
  });
});

export default io;
```

Client.ts

```
import { ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents } from "main/socket";
import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";

// "undefined" means the URL will be computed from the `window.location` object
const URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? undefined : 'http://localhost:8081';

// please note that the types are reversed
export const socket: Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents> = io(URL, {
  autoConnect: false
});

socket.emit("hello");

socket.on("noArg", () => {
  // ...
});

socket.on("basicEmit", (a, b, c) => {
  // a is inferred as number, b as string and c as buffer
});

socket.on("withAck", (d, callback) => {
  // d is inferred as string and callback as a function that takes a number as argument
});

socket.connect();
```

And started server in main.ts

```
  io.listen(8081);
```

In server.ts you will see `origin: "http://localhost:1212"` this is CORS to avoid issues warnings. Port `1212` is number that is used in my Electron app as http server port. Details https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors